# Make [ios-16] and add it as synonym of [ios]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest making [ios-16](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-16) and adding it as a synonym of [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios).

[ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) already contains [recovery-mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode), [ios-beta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-beta), [ios-12](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-12), [ios13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios13), [ios-13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-13), [ios14](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios14) and [ios-15](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-15).

Since iOS 16 got released in the end of 2022, I think it's time to create that tag and link it to [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios).

I have seen a lot of questions about iPhone that were updated to iOS 16 or more and had problems.

I think this could be quite helpful to differenciate between iOS versions. Also, there are tags for every iOS versions since iOS 12, why could we not add [ios-16](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-16)?

PS: Why is there [ios13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios13) and [ios-13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-13)? One of them should be removed don't you think?

Comment: Synonyms are just pointers, you can never set `ios-16` as a tag itself, will always end up as `ios` (try with `recovery-mode`:-)). So having version specific tags will not help to differenciate anything. I rather wonder whether we should get rid of the version synonyms (I also wonder why we made `recovery-mode` a synonym for `ios`, but that's most likely a different story).

Comment: @nohillside Yes, that's what I noticed but I thought about following the trend of adding synonyms for different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep in mind that tags should be created if they provide significant benefits in finding relevant topics (we are not a library so having a nice tag structure has not a lot of value). iOS version tags got created sometimes when a new version was released with significant differences to the previous one, and helped to group questions related to the new version. After a while we tended to turn them into synonyms.

The fact that nobody considered a `ios-16` tag to be necessary so far is IMHO rather an indicator that `ios` is good enough.